# WebView to PDFDocument

Tags: cocoa

I tried to get a PDFDocument from a WebView but I only got a part of the Page :-(

The code I used is this:

```
//Generate a PDF document from the HTML.
NSData *pdfData = [webView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[webView frame]];
PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:pdfData];

[document writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/tmp/test.pdf"]];
```

Any idea how to make it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the web view's main frame.
2. Get the main frame's frame view.
3. Get the main frame view's document view.
4. Get the PDF data from that, passing the document view's bounds (not frame) for the rect.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSData *pdfData = [[[[webview mainFrame] frameView] documentView] dataWithPDFInsideRect:[[[webview mainFrame] frameView] documentView].frame]; 
PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:pdfData];
[document writeToFile:@"/Users/PalmAgent/Desktop/test.pdf"];
```

Comment: It creates one page pdf.how to get multipage pdf?

Comment: it will work for multipage PDF also. Are you sure you have added exactly the above code? particularly the 'documentView'?